# Compute the limit as n approaches infinity involving a combinatoric identity

Tags: combinatorics, limits

I don't see how the following inequality holds:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{n}k\frac1{n^k}=\frac1{k!}$$

I'm having trouble seeing the equality. 
Could I get a graphical of algebraic solution? I can't graph the thing on the left side as a function using wolfram alpha. Using l'hospital quickly becomes a multivariable derivative pain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting $$\binom{n}k\frac1{n^k}=\frac{n!}{k!\,(n-k)!\,n^k}=\frac 1{k!}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\,n^k}$$ you then want to show that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\,n^k}=1$$ So, consider
$$A=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\,n^k}\implies \log(A)=\log(n!)-\log(n-k)!)-k \log(n)$$ Now use Stirling approximation $$\log(p!)=p (\log (p)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log
   \left({p}\right)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)$$and appply it to the two factorials neglecting the negative powers of $p$. This gives, after some minor simplifications
$$\log(A)=-k+(n-k+\frac 12)\log\left(\frac n {n-k} \right)$$
$$\log\left(\frac n {n-k} \right)=-\log\left(1-\frac kn \right)=\frac{k}{n}+\frac{k^2}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ $$\log(A)\approx -k+\left(n-k+\frac 12\right)\left(\frac{k}{n}+\frac{k^2}{2 n^2}\right)=-\frac{k(k-1)}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which makes $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(A)=0 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}A=1$$ and then the result.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
  \lim_{n\to\infty} \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k} 
      &= \frac{1}{k!}\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\frac{1}{n^k}\\
      &= \frac{1}{k!}\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-(k-1))(n-k)(n-(k+1))\cdots 2\cdot 1}{(n-k)(n-(k+1))\cdots 2\cdot 1\cdot n^k}\\
      & = \frac{1}{k!}\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-(k-1))}{n^k}.
\end{align*}

Comment: how did you get (n-(k-1)) in the numerator in the last step?

Comment: how did you get rid of the (n-k)! in the denominator?

Comment: Just expand $(n-k)! = (n-k)(n-(k+1))\cdots 2\cdot 1$ and cancel terms from the numerator.

Comment: How do you know $n(n-1)...(n-(k-1))$ /  $n^k$ limit as n approaches infinity is one?

Comment: We don't know what k is so we don't know what $n^k$ is

Comment: The limit is 1 (assuming $k>0$) since both numerator and denominator are polynomials of degree $k$ with a leading coefficient of $1$; the limit is the ratio of the leading coefficients.

Comment: how do you know num and denom  are of same degree k?

Comment: Count the number of factors in the numerator!